# Backbone inheritance and declarative events binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I am working on a Backbone application. I have created a parent view. Every view extends that parent. But in my case declarative event binding is not working.

```
  var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var model = this.model; 
        if(model instanceof Function) {
            model = model();
        }
        var template = _.template(tpl.get(this.templateId), model);
        this.$el.html(template);

        if(this.postRender && this.postRender instanceof Function) {
            this.postRender();
        }

        return this;
    },

    initialize : function (options) {
        this.options = options || {};
    }
});

   var MainMenuView = BaseView.extend({

    templateId: 'main-menu-tpl',

    events: {
        "click #prev" : "previous"
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.model =  {
                mainMenu: new MainMenu({title: 'CATEGORIES'})
        };
    },


    initRender: function(menuItems){
        this.model.mainMenu.set({"menuItems": menuItems});
        return this.render();
    },

    previous: function(){
        alert("Previous called");
    }

});
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: A sample code/Fiddle to illustrate how your code fails? An explanation of the problem?

Comment: Can you show more code from your parentView? Do you have events there as well?

Comment: I am trying to create a sample on jsfiddle and it worked actually :P but my code is not working sorry can't post that code here. Trying to see if I have made any mistake. I do not have any events in parentView.

Comment: Are they together in a single .js file? if they're not maybe you're load sequence is wrong?

Comment: No they are in different orders and I am loading Parent first

Comment: I have updated my code above. Let me know if you see anything wrong here